# unable to run build command successfully on a sveltekit project

Tags: firebase, build, sveltekit

I want to deploy my sveltikit App on Firebase but unable to run build command successfully  getting error:

[vite-plugin-sveltekit-setup] ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '\?\C:\Users\User\my-CV.svelte-kit\output\server\chunks'
error during build:

`your text`package.json

{
"name": "my-cv",
"version": "0.0.1",
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite dev",
"build": "vite build",
"preview": "vite preview",
"check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json",
"check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json --watch"

```
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.10",
    "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0-next.106",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.5",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-adapter-firebase": "^0.14.4",
    "svelte-check": "^2.10.3",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
},
"type": "module",
"dependencies": {
    "@rodneylab/svelte-social-icons": "^0.0.24",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.21.0"
}
```

}